# php function database connection

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with mysql database connection using a php function. I can't seem to get my function to call the database connection and return any data. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$useID=$_POST['use_id'];

function dbConnect(){
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "name", "pword", "path");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
return $conn;
}

function dropDown(){
$conn=dbConnect();
$query="SELECT * FROM usesList";
$myData = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($myData);
$options="";

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($myData)) {
  $options.="<option value='" . $row['use_id'] ."' >" . $row['use_name'] ."    
</option>";
 }
}
dropDown();?>
```

Comment: You'll want to look into PDO. It's a much better way to work with databases. http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Is there a relevant error?

Comment: you never bothered checking if the query succeeds. then you fetch and throw away the first row of results as well...

Comment: Why is there `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($myData);` before you loop through the rows? If the result contains only one row, you won't see anything, as Marc B pointed out.

Comment: Good points all, thanks for them, You helped me realise, I'm not returning the results with the function. Good lesson. Slowly learning.